# VS2017 SQLite DataAdapter and DataRelation

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2017

The SQLite modules I am using in VS2017 Community do not seem to have some methods ie

```
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using (SqliteConnection dbc = new SqliteConnection("Filename=emp.db")) {
    dbc.Open() ;
    SQLiteDataAdapter masterDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from 
    EMP", dbc);
}
```

just doesn't work, there is no SQLiteDataAdapter, or the equivalant DataRelation.

This may not really be a stackoverflow problem, but thought I'd ask, if anyone could point me in the right direction it'd be appreciated. I've found SQLite with this version of VS to be a bit of a pain.

Comment: Did you add the Microsoft.Data.SQLite nuget package to your solution https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/

Comment: Yes, I have Microsoft.Data.Sqlite, Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core, System.Data.SQLite, System.Data.SQLite.Core and a bunch of SQLite.PCL* packages, as well as System.Data.SQLite.EF6 and EntityFramework  I've been playing whack-a-mole with packages   I should have been more specific the error is actually SQLiteDataAdapter not found

Answer (score 1):

I think I see the problem. There is a Microsoft.Data.Sqlite and a System.Data.SQLite - note the difference in capitalisation. System.Data.SQLite has the method SQLiteDataAdapter. It also has SQLiteConnection - again, different caps.

So, I'm now using System.Data.SQLite.

I've yet to find out why there are the two packages doing ostensibly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working with a parent/child DataGridView using a Department/Employee test SQLite database

```
using System.Data.SQLite;
string DbConnectionString = @"Data Source=Emp.db;Version=3;";
using (SQLiteConnection dbc = new SQLiteConnection(DbConnectionString))
{
try
{
    dbc.Open();

    DataSet data = new DataSet();
    SQLiteDataAdapter departmentDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from DEPARTMENT", dbc);
    departmentDataAdapter.Fill(data, "DEPARTMENT");
    SQLiteDataAdapter empDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from EMP", dbc);
    empDataAdapter.Fill(data, "EMP");
    DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("EMPDPEP", data.Tables["DEPARTMENT"].Columns["DEPNO"], data.Tables["EMP"].Columns["DEPNO"]);
    data.Relations.Add(relation);

    masterBindingSource.DataSource = data;
    masterBindingSource.DataMember = "DEPARTMENT";
    detailsBindingSource.DataSource = masterBindingSource;
    detailsBindingSource.DataMember = "EMPDPEP";

    dbc.Close();

    DEPGridView.DataSource = masterBindingSource;
    EMPGridView.DataSource = detailsBindingSource;

    DEPGridView.AutoResizeColumns();
    EMPGridView.AutoResizeColumns();

}


catch (SQLiteException ex) 
{
    MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Stop", ex.Message.ToString(), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` is a different Namespace than
`System.Data.Sqlite`.

`DataAdapter` is not a part of `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite`.